# Check whether bytes in a byte array are Unicode

Tags: java, android, unicode, byte

How can I check whether bytes in a byte array are Unicode characters?

**main probleme:**

```
android 4.2 new String(bytes) remove unicode chars from my String: [\uFFFD]
```

I need a workaround for this.

Comment: You do know that a unicode character can be encoded on several bytes, right?

Comment: Are we talking about UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32?

Comment: \uFFFD isn't a real unicode character. It is a placeholder for a character that is unrepresentable in unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder().canEncode(string);
```

UPDATE: You didn't pass a `Charset` to `new String(bytes)`, so it just assumes you're using the default charset.  Instead, do e.g. `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: see the main probleme section

Comment: new String(bytes, "UTF-8") give me the same String in android 4.2, without my unicode [\uFFFD], strange thing: if I use new String(bytes, "UTF-8") under 4.2, that not working too, remove my unicode char, only if I use new String(bytes).

Comment: Then wherever you're getting the bytes _from_, it's probably not UTF-8 encoded; it's using some other encoding.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. You can guess, by observing that the characters in the byte array don't violate UTF-8 rules, for example. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx for some more information.